# Set specific item always on top recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I know how to set newly added item on top but here I want to stay specific item on top while new item has been added many time.

Here I upload one [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIDne.jpg)
You can find here What I want.

In that picture you can see new joined team stay always on top while many team joined by other devices. In other words in that picture user can see own team always on top. while other user has been added teams.

Here is my code

```
  public LeaderBoardFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_leader_board, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.leaderboard_recycler);
        wp10ProgressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.wp10progressBar);
        wp10ProgressBar.showProgressBar();

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
//        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(itemAnimator);
////        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
        return view;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        itemAnimator = new DefaultItemAnimator();
//        itemAnimator.setAddDuration(5000);
//        itemAnimator.setRemoveDuration(5000);
        getLeaderBoardData();
    }

    private void getLeaderBoardData() {
        Sharedpref sharedpref = Sharedpref.getInstance(getActivity());
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()));
        intent = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getIntent();
        matchId = sharedpref.getString("matchId");
        leaderboardArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("match", matchId);
        Log.d(TAG  + "112", String.valueOf(params));



        String Url = Constants.Base_URL + "leaderboard/";

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Url, new JSONObject(params),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(response));

                        try {

                            String statusObject = response.getString("status");
                            String msgObject = response.getString("msg");

                            if (statusObject.equals("200")) {
                                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("response");

                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject projResponse = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String rankObject = projResponse.getString("rank");
                                    String killsObject = projResponse.getString("kills");
                                    String myteamObject = projResponse.getString("myteam");


                                    Log.d("response", rankObject);
                                    Log.d("response", killsObject);
                                    Log.d("response", myteamObject);

//                                    Collections.reverse(leaderboardArrayList);
                                    leaderboardArrayList.add(new Leaderboard(rankObject, killsObject, myteamObject));

                                }

                                leaderBoardAdapter = new LeaderBoardAdapter(getContext(), leaderboardArrayList);

                                recyclerView.setAdapter(leaderBoardAdapter);
                                leaderBoardAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
                                leaderBoardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

//                        prizeAdapter.setOnItemClickListner(WingsActivity.this);
                                wp10ProgressBar.hideProgressBar();
                            }else {
                                wp10ProgressBar.hideProgressBar();
//                        shimmerLayout.stopShimmerAnimation();
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), msgObject, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }



                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        queue.add(request);

    }
```

Comment: Well before further studying what is the need of `leaderBoardAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);` and `leaderBoardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` at the same time. I think its meaningless!

Comment: ok I removed but nothing has been changed

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort your `leaderboardArrayList` with a custom sorter. That way you put top elements on top (I guessed there was only one), and other elements are sorted on any properties you want (like a date, a max amount ...)

```java
Collections.sort(leaderboardArrayList, (a, b) -> {
    //mustBeOnTop is a custom method that return true if this object is the one you want on top of your list
    if(1 == a.user_id) return -1;
    if(1 == b.user_id) return 1;
    return a.joinedDate.compareTo(b.joinedDate); //compare their "join" date
});

leaderBoardAdapter = new LeaderBoardAdapter(getContext(), leaderboardArrayList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(leaderBoardAdapter); //don't need to call any notification method of the adapter
```

Comment: can you elaborate your method make more specific for me. How can I do if I want to sort with user_name (BlackBlind) . It is more helpful for me

Comment: what are sorting rules ? What makes an item on top, and how are sorted all other items ? With your answer I'll write sort methods ;)

Comment: user_id 1 will always on top while other user has been joined .